# Select option not displaying in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

The following select options display fine in Firefox/Chrome but not in IE8. Please help.

```
<select id = "vehicle" name = "vehicle" class = "vehicleSelect">
<option value = "-1" selected>&nbsp;</option>
<option value = "15">Car</option>
<option value = "16">Bike</option>
<option value = "17">Train</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.vehicleSelect
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font: 10px/1.45em "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding: 3;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, make sure your padding has a unit. 3 alone is meaningless.

Comment: Just to clarify, which version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: As my physics teacher would say: 3 what? 3 watermelons per second? 3 parrots per tree? UNITS! UNITS!

Comment: @DrydenLong ie8 as the question indicates

Comment: try it without the width and height being 100%, what does it look like in ie8? if you put this code alone in a fiddle, it also does not display correctly in FF

Comment: In what way don't they display fine in IE8?

Comment: @Huangism Ah, I must of skipped right over that, +1 for doing the reading for me. lol

Comment: I removed the spaces and added units to padding. There was also another issue in my CSS which I corrected. Now, it displays fine in IE too. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the standard border in the select box, so it will naturally look strange in various browsers. Consider removing `height: 100%` and `border:0`.

You also shouldn't add spacing in your HTML tag properties. It could cause various issues depending on the browser, plus it's just good practice.

```
<select id = "vehicle" name = "vehicle" class = "vehicleSelect">
```

Should be:

```
<select id="vehicle" name="vehicle" class="vehicleSelect">
```

Comment: I removed the spaces and added units to padding. There was also another issue in my CSS which I corrected. Now, it displays fine in IE too. Thanks all!